# Testing Ethernet POE and surge\transients from other sources like lightning

Tags: poe

I've got a POE Powered Device (PD) that I would like to make sure the surge protection is functioning in the event of a surge that it doesn't take down my device. How could I test for surge\transient over POE?

Comment: I was going to ask this question, but then found the answer and decided to write it up for others.

Comment: Which surges do you need to meet?

Comment: I don't have any hard reqs but I don't want the product to fail out in the field, so thought I'd look for something to test it with

Answer (score 0):

TI offers a circuit to test transients over POE.

[image]
Source: slua736

Comment: I googled for fun: "A typical lightning flash is about 300 million Volts and about 30,000 Amps." That's gonna be one hefty 20uF capacitor 

Comment: It's not a direct hit, just indirect transients

Comment: It might be better to use the indirect lightning spec EN 61000-4-5. It describes the waveforms, the peak voltage for each class and the series current-limiting impedance of the waveform. Then, you just simulate and see how much power is dissipated in the TVSs. You don't need to buy the spec; there are several on-line documents that give you enough details to make a generator or simulate it.